# SharePoint provider-hosted app filter document library CSOM

Tags: visual-studio, csom, provider-hosted-app, mvc

I have the following code that gets files from a document library. Works great for getting all the files. Now, however, I want to filter the files using the "title" param before passing it back to my MVC controller.

```
public IEnumerable<File> FindBy(string title, ClientContext clientContext)
{
    var documentLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
    clientContext.Load(documentLibrary);
    Folder folder = documentLibrary.RootFolder;
    clientContext.Load(folder);

    var files = folder.Files;
    clientContext.Load(files);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    return files;
}
```

Any ideas? I have tried using the

```
files.Select(x => x.files.Name.Contains(title))
```

Which turns it into an `IQueryable<bool>` but I can't get it back to the method's type of `IEnumerable<File>`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem. I changed my code to use the ListItemCollection instaed of FileCollection and used a CAML query to filter. Also, since I still need the File object (for the server relative Url), I loaded it in the context:

```
public IEnumerable<ListItem> FindBy(string fileName, ClientContext clientContext)
{
    var documentLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
    clientContext.Load(documentLibrary);

    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
    query.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>" + filename + @"</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
    ListItemCollection listItems = documentLibrary.GetItems(query);
    clientContext.Load(listItems, includes => includes.Include(i => i["FileLeafRef"], i => i.File));

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    return listItems;
}
```